# Swap items between two recyclerView lists

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments `i_have` and `to_buy` of a `pageView`.
Both of them have list of items created using recyclerView.
I have two different adapters `infoAdapter` and `info2Adapter`for both of the fragments respectively.

I have set an `onClickListner` on the icon(image) of each item, which on click deletes the item

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;
    TextView amt;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_have_row_name);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_have_row_image);
        amt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_have_row_amount);
        icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        delete(getPosition());        
    }
}
```

The delete method is as follows

```
public void delete(int position){
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Now what I want is, whenever an item gets deleted from `i_have`, it should automatically get added to the `to_buy` and vice verse.

I have created an `add` method in the adapter of `to_buy` class

```
public void add(String s){
    Information2 information2 = new Information2();
    information2.name2 = s;
    information2.iconId2 = R.drawable.potatoes;
    information2.amount = "1KG";
    data2.add(0,information);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But I am confused how to call this method from the adapter of `i_have` class. As it is a non-static method, which object should I use to call the add method? I created an object of another class but I am not sure where should I reference it to?

[EDIT]

I implemented what yshahsk said in the answer but I need to add a parameter in `MyViewHolder` call.

The `onCreateViewHolder()` is as follows:

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.i_have_row, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
```

[EDIT2]

As requested

here is my adapter file `infoAdapter` for the i_have fragment.

```
package example.srujan.com.exapp4;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Srujan on 14-07-2015.
 */
public class infoAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<infoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList() ;


public infoAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

public void delete(int position){
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void add(String s){
    Log.d("TAG",data.size()+" String received: "+s);
    Information information = new Information();
    information.name = s;
    information.iconId = R.drawable.potatoes;
    information.amount = "1KG";
    data.add(0,information);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.i_have_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.name);
    holder.amt.setText(current.amount);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;
    TextView amt;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_have_row_name);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_have_row_image);
        amt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i_have_row_amount);
        icon.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        delete(getPosition());
        //Log.d("TAG3","String passed 2: Tametu");
        //add("Tomatu");
    }
}
}
```

Here is my another adapter `info2Adapter`, this one for to_buy

```
package example.srujan.com.exapp4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Srujan on 19-07-2015.
 */
public class info2Adapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<info2Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information2> data2 = Collections.emptyList() ;


public info2Adapter(Context context, List<Information2> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data2=data;
}

//TEST PURPOSE
public info2Adapter() {

}

//    public void addToBuy(Information2 i){
//        Information2 current = new Information2();
//        current.name2 = i.name2;
//        current.iconId2 = i.iconId2;
//        data2.add(current);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_buy_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information2 current = data2.get(position);
    //holder.title.setText(current.name);
    holder.title.setText(current.name2);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId2);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data2.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_buy_row_name);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_buy_row_image);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some way to do this. Here suggestion:

```
public class infoAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<infoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private LayoutInflater inflater;
   List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList() ;
   Activity activity;


   public infoAdapter(Activity activity, List<Information> data){
       inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
       this.data=data;
       this.activity = activity;
   }

   public void delete(int position){
       String removed = data.remove(position);
       notifyItemRemoved(position);
       activity.yourSecondAdapter.add(removed);
   }

   //rest of your adapter class

}
```

You may need to do some additional adjusments.

Comment: Can you help me with the `super()` of `MyViewHolder(Activity activity)` please?

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed to you constructor. Edited my answer

Comment: To get this work I'll have to pass an instance of `mySecondAdapter` where I make a call `MyViewHolder()` i.e. `MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view,instanceOfSecondAdapter);` What should I pass as the second parameter?

Comment: No you don't. If  your adapters are fields you can just pass the Activity and access to that field. If not, then you need to pass the adapter. If you don't know how edit your question so it will contain the activity onCreate so I can help you with that if you have issues with this

Comment: Okay, let me reframe the question.

Comment: Added it as [EDITs] so it is easier for others to refer. Do let me know if you want more of the code!

Comment: You need to hand the activity in the Adapter constructor. I edited my answer

Comment: unable to implement. :| tried hard but not getting results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83843/discussion-between-yshahak-and-srujan-barai).

Comment: almost getting it. but `yourSecondActivity` in `activity.yourSecondAdapter.add(removed);` is doing all the problem.
`

Comment: You need to access to the second adapter as you definded it. Did you define it as field in the  Activity?

Comment: I have main activity with three fragments and all the adapters as different class files to inflate each fragment.  Did this answer your question?

Comment: No. You just need to access the info2Adapter you use in setAdapter() on the the second recycleView

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours I managed to do this (not elegant way). i declared fragment2's arraylist as static(not good practice). Just add in the infoadapter's viewholder the following code with adjustments:

```
    deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Firstitems item = mArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                mArrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                Fragment2.mArrayListActress.add(item);

            }
        });
```